# Why no errors are stored in the specified error_log file?

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, error-handling

I want to save errors from a specific file in a custom file, Not the default file.

So I added that at the top of my script:

```
ini_set("log_errors", TRUE);
ini_set("error_log", get_template_directory_uri() . "/errors.log");
```

Then I removed a character from a function to create an error:

```
echo $date->fomat("F j, Y");
//Should be format("F j, Y")
```

That caused a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::fomat()
```

But I can't see any text in the log file.

I read a comment saying that `ini_set` works only when the code is executed, So I have to edit that function in `php.ini`.

But I want only to save that script errors in that custom file, Not all the errors, As I will parse that errors into a section on the website.

I can't use :

```
try {
    //Script Here.
} catch (Exception $e) {
    file_put_contents(get_template_directory_uri() . "/errors.log", $e->message);
}
```

Because that won't get all the fatal errors, Warnings and notices.

What to do then to get that script errors saved in a separate file?

Comment: I don't think this can be done. Anyone?

Comment: It's resolved now

Comment: If so, then do tell us, please.

Comment: When I tired a custom message `error_log("Hello, errors!", 3, get_template_directory_uri() . "/errors.log");`

Comment: I got that error `Warning: error_log(): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections `

Comment: Hmmm, that has got the same problem: You code needs to compile first.

Comment: So I edited `get_template_directory_uri()`, To `get_template_directory`

Comment: Ok, so you're accepting that things like syntax errors will still go into the normal log file.

Comment: These errors from that script are inserted to that custom `errors.log` file not the default file

Comment: It's considered as a fatal error, Could I specify what errors to store?